# Expressing $\mathbb{C}^3$ as a direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, direct-sum

$S_3$ acts on $\lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$, so this affords a homomorphism $S_3\to GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ (acting on $\mathbb{C}^3$). I showed the only vector fixed by the action of $S_3$ is zero.

> Find two different vector subspaces $U,V$ preserved by the image of $S_3$ such that $\mathbb{C}^3=U\oplus V$.

How can $U,V$ be constructed? Since $U$ has to be fixed by permutations of its three components, its elements must be of the form $(a+bi,a+bi,a+bi)$, and the same can be said for $V$. Based on this fact, I cannot see how $\mathbb{C}^3=U+V$. For example, $(0,1,0)$ will not belong to either $U$ or $V$.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ only have to be preserved by $S_3$ as _sets_.  Each individual element of $U$ doesn't have to be fixed by each element of $S_3$; each element of $S_3$ just has to send it to some other element of $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some misunderstanding in the requirement of the task: You are required to find subspaces that are as sets stable under the permutation action, but not necessarily element-wise.

Concerning your comment on $(0,1,0)$ neither belonging to $U$ nor $V$: note that ${\mathbb C}=U\oplus V$ does not imply that any $v\in {\mathbb C}^3$ belongs to either $U$ or $V$, but only that it can be written as a linear combination of elements of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Isn't $S_3$ acting on $U$ by permuting its elements?

Comment: How can $U$ be stable unless it's elements are of the form $(x,x,x)$?

Comment: Look for example at the set of vectors having exactly two entries with value $0$ and one entry with value $1$; it is stable - again, _as a set_ - under the permutation of action, but none of its members is.

Comment: That makes sense, but why shouldn't order be considered? It wasn't obvious to me to consider sets stable under the action modulo the order.

Comment: Oh, no, the order _is_ considered: the elements $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are considered different! The point is you look for subspaces such that when you permute one element of it, you get another. So with each vector all its reorderings are again in the subspace.

Comment: @cap Is everything clear now?

Comment: The objective is clear. I'm struggling to find nontrivial choices for $U, V$.